# Load and authenticate into a web within an iframe using http, from a web using https

Tags: php, http, https, file-get-contents, php-curl

I need to simulate from within an iframe in our site, which uses **https** and it's loaded only once upon the authentication on our site, the authentication into another site, which only uses **http**.

How can I do that?

We first tried loading into the iframe a page of our site from which the login form for the remote authentication is automatically submitted with javascript. This cannot be achieved because the http request from the form is blocked by the browser for security reasons. I must clarify that if we use http in our web too, the authentication is done without problems.

I'm not sure if using ***file_get_contents()*** will do the trick, because it's not a simple static page what we need to display. We need to keep any data from the remote login (cookies, etc) in the browser so that we can access other parts of the remote web (once I've signed in) from other places of our site. As far as I know, file_get_contents doen't provide any header.

Another alternative I've also considered is **curl**, using **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER**=true and **CURLOPT_HEADER**=true and trying to manually set any cookies I get in the header. I'm not sure if keeping the session implies more actions though.

Comment: You can't do that, for very good reasons.

Comment: @ceejayoz could you please explain a little? It can't be done the regular way, but I'm sure there must be hacks to do it.

Comment: You can't include HTTP assets on a HTTPS site, and you can't set cookies for the remote site in your users' browsers. If you try to proxy the whole thing, it's going to be a nightmare of parsing and broken stuff.